# Java HtmlUnit select option without name or id

Tags: java

How do i select the option `Speedserver` with **HtmlUnit** ? 
It has no id or name so i dont know how to select it.
I read something about xPath but how do i use it ?

Here is the html code:

```
<select name="server" id="serverselector">
    <option value="">Server</option>
    <option value='s1.'>Server 1</option>
    <option value='server2.'>Server 2</option>
    <option value='speed.'>Speedserver</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, use [`getElementByID(#serverselector)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) to get `HtmlElement` by ID, then use:

1. `getElementsByTagName("option")` on it to get all the HtmlElements
   with `option` tag and go through them with
   [`getTextContent("Speedserver")`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getTextContent%28%29) and check the text content to be matched.
2. **or**, use [`getElementsByAttribute("option", "value", "speed")`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html#getElementsByAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on it.

Comment: So is HtmlElement test = page.getElementByAttribute("option", "value", "speed"); right ?

Comment: yes probably it would. But first getting by ID `#serverselector` and then get by attribute `(name, value)` is more appropriate.